# Updating data into Database

Tags: c#, linq, datagridview, updating

I have problems adding data into the database. The code that I have written could only update the shiftTiming_Start but not the shiftTiming_Stop. Can someone please help take a look at my code and see what went wrong. Thanks a lot.

```
private void btnUpdate_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
  using (testEntities Setupctx = new testEntities()) {
    var toBeUpdated = txtStart.Text;
    var toBeUpdated1 = txtStop.Text;
    shifthour updateShift = new shifthour();
    updateShift = Setupctx.shifthours.FirstOrDefault(u => u.shiftTiming_start == toBeUpdated);
    updateShift = Setupctx.shifthours.FirstOrDefault(p => p.shiftTiming_stop == toBeUpdated1);
    updateShift.shiftTiming_start = txtStart.Text;
    updateShift.shiftTiming_stop = txtStop.Text;
    Setupctx.SaveChanges();
    txtStart.Text = "";
    txtStop.Text = "";
    MessageBox.Show("Shift Timing Has Been Updated.");
  }
}
```

Comment: Note that the `updateShift = Setupctx.shifthours.FirstOrDefault(u => u.shiftTiming_start == toBeUpdated);` is effectively discarded by the subsequent similar line involving `p`; is that the record you are trying to update?

Comment: both 'u' and 'p' are the one that I am going to update. But for now I can only update the 'u' and not the 'p'.

Comment: have you checked by putting a break point if their is anything inside txtStop.Text

Comment: Yea I have checked. The data does not update the database. If I update just the start time, it can be updated but if I update both together, both can't be updated.

Comment: @Philemon no, right now you're only updating the `p` one; the `u` one is fetched but discarded.

Comment: So how am I supposed to make both of the Shift time to be updated? I'm real lost.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming I'm following you correctly (I would recommend using more meaningful variable names), update the code as follows:

```
private void btnUpdate_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
  using (testEntities Setupctx = new testEntities()) {
    var toBeUpdatedStart = txtStart.Text;
    var toBeUpdatedStop = txtStop.Text;
    shifthour updateStartShift;
    shifthour updateStopShift;
    updateStartShift = Setupctx.shifthours.FirstOrDefault(u => u.shiftTiming_start == toBeUpdatedStart);
    updateStopShift = Setupctx.shifthours.FirstOrDefault(p => p.shiftTiming_stop == toBeUpdatedStop);
    if (updateStartShift != null)
    {
       updateStartShift.shiftTiming_start = txtStart.Text;
    }
    if (updateStopShift != null)
    {
        updateStopShift.shiftTiming_stop = txtStop.Text;
    }
    Setupctx.SaveChanges();
    txtStart.Text = "";
    txtStop.Text = "";
    MessageBox.Show("Shift Timing Has Been Updated.");
  }
}
```

Comment: I tried out your codes and when I compile the error showed me was 'Sequence contains no element'. This is the line that they highlighted. "updateShiftStart = Setupctx.shifthours.Single(u => u.shiftTiming_start == toBeUpdatedStart);"  And by the way, the textboxes has already had data in it which I select from the datagridview and can't be possibly null right?

Comment: Can you post the exact code you're using?  I'm not sure how there's an error on  "updateShiftStart = Setupctx.shifthours.Single(u => u.shiftTiming_start == toBeUpdatedStart);" since I did not include that in my suggestion.  FirstOrDefault is safer because if it doesn't find a match, it will return null.  The textbox value is very unlikely to be null, but updateStartShift is likely to be null in the event that shifthours in Setupctx doesn't have any matching values.  Based on the error you described, either Setupctx.shifthours is an empty list, or there is no element matching your criteria.